# multiple values per row to file - python

Tags: python, csv, file-io, python-3.5

I'm trying to store scores per user to a file in python and I'm not being able to.

I have two lists, `names[]` & `points[]`. Everytime the program runs it appends user and score, but when it's run again, the score in the file gets overwritten rather than added to that user.

```
def quiz():

names=[]
points=[]
name=input("What is your name?")
for x in range (0,1)
    pnt=0  
    num1=3
    num2=4
    print("Whats", num1, '+', num2)
    answer = num1+num2
 userAns=int(input())
 if userAns==answer:
    print("Excellent")
    pnt = pnt+1
 else:
    print("wrong") 
    print("Well done", name, "you scored", point, "/10")
    points.append(point)
    names.append(name)
    class_name = class_name + ".csv"   
    c=open(class_name , 'a+') ##This part forward it prints to another row rather then appending score in the same row
    mw = csv.writer(c)
    rows = zip(names,points)
    mw.writerows(rows)
    c.close()
```

I need to print the user and then multiple scores alongside it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is no `User[] & Score[]` in your program!

Comment: apologies! silly mistake, sorry. I was thinking one thing writing another.

Comment: If I may say so, this is so 1980s. It's really cumbersome to store things in raw files like this. It's so much easier to use a database.

Comment: @e4c5 true, but it's just something I'm experimenting with

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your code cannot be run, and it does not look like what it does what it should be doing even other than the part about appending values to the same row. I am confused as to what the actual requirements are for what you are trying to do, but to append values to the same row (assuming each user gets his own file):

```
c=open(class_name , 'a+')
```

can be changed to

```
c=open(class_name , 'rb+')  # csv are considered as binary files
c.seek(-2,2) # go to \r\n
mv.writerows(   #... write now
```

Alternatively, if all users and scores are in the same file (which seems to be what you want, based on your description), you can simply replace the contents of the current file, so just write to it normally and replace the existing contents